# PHP deleting $i from an array using unset. I have a hole in my array and can't fix it

Tags: php, arrays, forms, unset, array-splice

This piece of my code deletes the item from the array using the value of `$i`. `$i=0;` when it starts, and when `$i=2` is deleted, the value that replaces it can't be deleted again. I know it's because I have a hole in my array using the **unset** function.

In my form, I set the value to `$i`.

`<input name='index_to_remove' type='hidden' value='" . $i . "' />`

and then processes the form with this:

```
if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        header("location: cart.php");
        } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        //sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        //$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array_values($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        //array_splice($_SESSION['cart_array'], $i, 1, array($_SESSION['cart_array']['key_to_remove'] + 1));
        }
    }
```

the commented out  are lines are the things i've tried and have failed miserably at. I've narrowed it down to this: the indicies are being deleted and then completely gone, so the new value that replaces the unset array item can't be deleted again.

I believe I have a hole in my array due to the

```
unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
```

I don't know what to add but I think I need to use array_splice so when a user deletes an item, and then tries to delete the same item again, it will always delete. Please help.

Comment: remove the `unset()` and instead use `array_splice($_SESSION['cart_array'], $key_to_remove, 1)`

Comment: Have you tried removing the `"`s? I don't think that's the problem, but definitely no need to have them.

Comment: @EugenRieck Just curious, what if I were to start my array at 1, and specify $i=1? Would I have to change the number to 0???? It works perfectly with $i=0 THANK YOU SO FREAKING MUCH!

Comment: I strongly recommend against using 1-based arrays in PHP - basically all functions for integer indices assume a zero-base.

Comment: I have a hole in my heart and I can't fix it...(couldn't resist)

Answer (score 2):

We ran into a very similar problem! Try resetting your indices using array_values:

`array_values(unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]));`

Comment: I got an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET), expecting ')'

Comment: This won't work.  `unset()` doesn't return a value.  This is essentially the same as `array_values();`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reorder anything; just use the index when you create the form elements:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $index => $value) {
    // ...
    printf(
        '<input type="hidden" name="index_to_remove " value="%d" />', 
        $index
    );
    // ...
}
```

To remove the item:

```
if (array_key_exists($key_to_remove, $_SESSION['cart_array'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$key_to_remove];
}
```

To add an item:

```
$_SESSION['cart_array'][] = ...;
```